# How to edit the torrc in "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" account?

Tags: relays, configuration

As the title say, how can I do it ?

I has made a decision to uninstall Vidalia and use only tor.exe to run as a relay. I have tried to install Tor into the service so it is not going to disturb me. But every time I tried to install Tor service, it will run using "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" account. Tor said that the torrc is stored into service user (means "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"), I tried google to find the directory of "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" but found nothing. So anyone have any idea on how can I change the torrc for "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all for the good answers, but I already solved my problem. After doing some trace using Process Monitor on my tor.exe service, it looks like my tor service data is stored on `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\tor\`, I'm happy man now. ;)

Also to add up a solution for future reference, I got this error message when trying to run tor.exe as a service `Service failed to start : An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.` is because of permission problem. The DataDirectory that I set in my torrc file is currently on the my account and another user process (tor.exe that running under `LocalService`) can't access DataDirectory files. So to fix it up, just set your DataDirectory on main directory on your local disk like `C:\torDatadDir\`. ;)

Comment: Don't forget to 'accept' your own answer by using the button just below the voting icons!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to run a Tor Relay as a Service on Windows.

Looking at the [Windows Service FAQ](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorFAQ#HowdoIrunmyTorrelayasanNTservice), it looks as though you can tell Tor to use a specific torrc when installing the service, for example `tor --service install -options -f C:\torrc`, this is the recommended way of modifying the torrc for a Windows Service installation.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I already tried that, but every time I run the command (with custom torrc), this error is out on the screen `Service failed to start : An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.`

Answer (score 1):

On my 2003 server I have Tor running as a service on the `LocalService` account.
The Tor data directory is in the `C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Application Data\tor` folder.
If you can't navigate to the `C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService` folder in the file explorer you have to type it in the address bar.

Comment: Thank you for your replied, I'm not using Windows Server of XP now, and I already search for that folder `C:\Users\LocalService\` but its show nothing.